# Using kafka state store change log topic to share state

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, event-sourcing

I am trying to do a small POC on event sourcing in the e-commerce domain. So I have an order service, a customer contact service and a delivery service. Now for logistical reasons, some customer contact information should be available to the delivery person so that they can call the customer in case they are not at home etc. Obviously, customers can update their contact information and the delivery should ideally show the latest contact info. I am using kafka as the messaging framework and state store.
When I create a state store by reading events related to an aggregate's state changes (e.g. customer contact info change) and apply them on the aggregate, the state store is backed with a change-log topic (e.g. contact-service-customer-contact-changelog). Now if I need some of this data in another service (e.g. delivery service) can I use the same change log topic to create another state store local to that service? In the literature available this type of topic is termed "internal" and so it seems we are not supposed to use this topic for anything other than re-building the state store for the instances of the original service. So we should be re-publishing the updates to the state store to a new topic for other services to join with this data? Or is there another way to address this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called internal topic because it's managed by the Kafka Streams library. This implies, that the topic name might change, and thus it might not be save to consume the topic. Nothing prevents you to consume the topic though.

To not mess up the state, you should never **write** to this topic though. Reading from it, is "conceptually save".

It's hard to advice and you should make your own decision to read the topic or to create a topic manually and write the same data a second time.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Matthias J. Sax. I'm not sure if the application name change or state store name change (The elements that make the changelog topic name) is going to be a very frequent occurrence, on the other hand, the network and computational overhead of publishing duplicate data seems to be too high considering hundreds of such aggregates in an enterprise. I will go ahead with re-using the changelog topic for now and see how it plays over time. Thanks again.